# Convert a standard label/input HTML to ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following HTML code which displays a CHECKBOX input:

```
<label class="label_check" for="sample-check">
    <input name="sample-check" id="sample-check" value="1" type="checkbox" />
    Sample Label
</label>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Whether a user clicks on the box or the text, the option gets selected.

What ASP control can I use so it works the same way it does in HTML? The reason being is I will be getting some column from my SQL table and create as many of those checkboxes in my page as there are columns from C#.

Comment: You can use the `<asp:Checkbox />` user control.

Comment: Are you using MVC? or Asp.Net webforms ?

Comment: Just using Asp.net controls by itself for now and trying to see if it will produce the same result. I am trying to emulate this: `http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/demo.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tasos Said in the Comments. You can use

```
<asp:Checkbox id="sample_check" runat="server" text="Sample Label"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. The ID will fail as it will not be valid.

Comment: I wondered about that but I couldn't remember for sure. I will Update my sample.

Comment: Trying to emulate this: http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/demo.html in ASP controls.

Comment: Once you get the checkboxes and radiobuttons added you're just going to have to work on styling. That's the tricky part.

Comment: That could have something to do with the with of the containing element. For instance if it is inside a `<div>` make sure that the `<div>` is wide enough.